# Updating <canvas/> with React and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I would expect the following code to cause React to

- render a canvas tag to the page, where the `<canvas>` contains the word 'foo'
- one second later change the props to 'bar'
- update the `<canvas>` with the word 'bar' AND update the `<span>` with the word 'bar'

The `<span>` updates but not the `<canvas>`

```
import React from 'react'

var CanvasTest = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount() {
    this.animate(this.props.text)
  },

  animate(str) {
    var c = document.getElementById('canvas')
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d')
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,10,50)
    ctx.fillText(str, 10, 50)
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{this.props.text}</span>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
      </div>
    )
  }

})

export default React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      str: 'foo'
    }
  },

  componentDidMount() {

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ str: 'bar' })
    }, 1000)

  },

  render() {
    return (
      <CanvasTest text={this.state.str}/>
    )
  }

})
```

Comment: You need to change the state to trigger the render function; `componentDidMount` will only be triggered once from your example you've provided. Have you reviewed the component life cycle diagram already? I would guess that you need to update the text in the `componentWillRecieveProps`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "componentWillReceiveProps" inside of CanvasTest

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    ctx.fillText(newProps.text, 10, 50);

    // to re-render
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Adding componentDidUpdate() { this.animate(this.props.text) } would have a similar effect. Both draw the word 'foo' on the canvas in fairness, but it's strange that rendering this.props.text into a <span> would work fine, but not with <canvas> it seems?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `clearRect` was only clearing a small part of the `canvas`, see params below:

```
animate(str) {
  var c = document.getElementById('canvas')
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d')
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  ctx.fillText(str, 10, 50)
},
```